# C++, function that loads text ignores last few lines with only some of the .txt files

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm following theForger's Win API tutorial to load text files into an edit control. Sometimes the entire file is loaded correctly and sometimes the last part of it is left out, where 'part' is in one case 2 and a half lines and in another 10 lines o_O Here's how the files look:

(I'm a new user so it's not letting me post more than one hyperlink, so here's the gallery where the screenshots are: http://nancy.imgur.com/all/ and I'm referring to the order in which they appear in the gallery)

2.5 lines left out:  second (reading stops at the cursor after the 'F')

10 lines left out: fourth (also stops at the cursor after the f)

Read completely: first and third

I tried using fstreams instead, and the same stuff was left out (I also couldn't get the new line characters to show in the edit control =( ). Any idea what could be wrong?

I couldn't link to theForger's tutorial so here's the function:

```
BOOL LoadTextFileToEdit(HWND hEdit, LPCTSTR pszFileName) {
HANDLE hFile;
BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

hFile = CreateFile(pszFileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD dwFileSize;

    dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    if(dwFileSize != 0xFFFFFFFF)
    {
        LPSTR pszFileText;

        pszFileText = GlobalAlloc(GPTR, dwFileSize + 1);
        if(pszFileText != NULL)
        {
            DWORD dwRead;

            if(ReadFile(hFile, pszFileText, dwFileSize, &dwRead, NULL))
            {
                pszFileText[dwFileSize] = 0; // Add null terminator
                if(SetWindowText(hEdit, pszFileText))
                    bSuccess = TRUE; // It worked!
            }
            GlobalFree(pszFileText);
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
return bSuccess; }
```

Comment: Is it possible that the input files contain ASCII NUL characters (0x00 bytes) at the point where they get cut off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that your text file contains embedded NUL characters, and therefore the string `pszFileText` is terminated earlier than you expect? The `SetWindowText()` function stops reading after it encounters the first NUL terminator.

Also, when reading from the file you will want to check that `dwRead` really is the number of bytes you wanted to read. What happens if `dwRead` is less than `dwFileSize`?

Comment: Yes, there was indeed an embedded NUL character, thank you! =D

Answer (score 0):

Right before calling `SetWindowText` call `strlen(pszFileText)` and compare that to `dwFileSize`.  It's possible that there was a `\0` in the file.

Answer (score 0):

There might be restrictions of edit control. By default amount of text a user can enter in edit control is limited to 32 KB. What is the size of your text files?